# How to remove the gap above and below the text on flutter

Tags: text, flutter, widget, padding

I am trying to put the text "Hello" right below the "123", but the bigger the text is, the bigger the gap. How do I remove the gap??? Flutter images are added below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's okay, can you show us your code?

Comment: added a link for the coded above

Comment: we can use **textHeightBehaviour** property of the Text widget.

 
`textHeightBehavior: const TextHeightBehavior(
                      applyHeightToFirstAscent: true,
                      applyHeightToLastDescent: false,
                    ),`

Answer (score 9):

The only way I could find so far is to reduce `height` property, the problem though is that it reduces the gap above only. So in your case, you could try to set it for `hello` text to the minimum:

```
Text(
   '123',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60.0),
),
Text(
   'hello',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, height: 0.1),
),
```

Comment: Add up to the answer. The hight must be greater than 0 to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Stack` widget to align your text widgets

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          '123',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60.0),
        ),
        Positioned(
          child: Text('Hello'),
          bottom: 0.0,
          left: 35.0,
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

**Debugging**
It helps to have the flutter inspect open so in the emulator you can see the bounding area for the Text Field. Select it so you can see the transparent overlay. This way you will be able to see the height of the Text() component.

**How it works.**

`textHeightBehavior` is the solution specifically with regards to Text() component. You can manipulat its settings to remove the bottom spacing and additionally not have to worry too much about the text styles height property.

`applyHeightToLastDescent` needs to be set to true and `applyHeightToFirstAscent` needs to be false. **Additionally** you need to set the `height` property of your `textStyle` to `0.1`. I use the `myTextStyle.copyWith(height:0.1)` to override the style for this specific siutation.

You might think that overriding `testStyle:height` is a bad thing, and typically i would say that it is, because your essentially overriding your primary text style. However, typically, when aligning a single line of text, in this kind of siutation your probably ok. If you have multiline text then it might be that this may not work for you. You'll have to experiment.

`leadingDistribution` doesn't have anyeffect as far as I can tell, and neither does the `textBaseLine` property.

When you inspect the Text field below in the Flutter inspector and you swap the true/false values, you'll hopefully see the effect your looking for. The leading below the text, usually present for letters like g, will dissapear.

Its possibly worth additionally seeing how this works with lower, or mixed case words. Components such as `Pills()`, or `Tags()` tend to be upper case.

```
Text(
    "HEADER",

    textHeightBehavior: const TextHeightBehavior(
        applyHeightToLastDescent: true,
        applyHeightToFirstAscent: false,
        leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even),

    style: currentStyle.headerStyle.copyWith(
           fontSize: 20,
           textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
           height: 0.1),
    ))
```

**Broader exmample of Text() within a Row().**

Swap POCButton out with your own icon or button component or a sized box. This is just code example for a common situation. I.e. Header nav.

```
 renderButtonRow() {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 32, 16, 8),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const POCButton(
              text: "Back",
              thinPadding: true,
            ),
            Align(
                heightFactor: 1,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  "HEADER",
                  textHeightBehavior: const TextHeightBehavior(
                      applyHeightToLastDescent: true,
                      applyHeightToFirstAscent: false,
                      leadingDistribution: TextLeadingDistribution.even),
                  style: currentStyle.headerStyle.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                      height: 0.1),
                )),
            const POCIcon(
              icon: POCIcons.settings,
              transparent: true,
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```