# Base align text and dashed line in Flutter

Tags: layout, flutter, styling

I'm trying to create something like this for my Flutter app:

[image]

Right now I've successfully got a row with text, a dashed line and larger text for the money. My last problem I can't seem to solve is getting rid of the variable size gap in different sized text.

[image]

[EDIT]
I specifically mean having everything aligned on the same red line:

[image]

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975216/how-to-remove-the-gap-above-and-below-the-text-on-flutter) I figured that I could do the same thing and place all the text in positioned stacks. That however breaks my layout giving me this error:

```sh
I/flutter (26439): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (26439): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter (26439): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
I/flutter (26439): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
I/flutter (26439): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
I/flutter (26439): space in the vertical direction.
I/flutter (26439): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
I/flutter (26439): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
I/flutter (26439): Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
I/flutter (26439): children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
I/flutter (26439): themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
I/flutter (26439): then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
I/flutter (26439): constraints provided by the parent.
I/flutter (26439): The affected RenderFlex is:
I/flutter (26439):   RenderFlex#c7fb1 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (26439): The creator information is set to:
I/flutter (26439):   Column ← Expanded ← Row ← Column ← Padding ← RepaintBoundary-[<0>] ← IndexedSemantics ←
I/flutter (26439):   NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← SliverList ←
I/flutter (26439):   MediaQuery ← ⋯
I/flutter (26439): See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/
```

Here is my relevant code:

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Salary Cap'),
    // Stack( // Will cause error
    //   fit: StackFit.expand,
    //   children: <Widget>[
    //     Positioned(
    //       top: 0,
    //       left: 0,
    //       width: 200,
    //       child: Text('Salary Cap'),
    //     ),
    //   ],
    // ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: CustomPaint(painter: LineDashedPainter()),
      ),
    ),
    RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(text: '\$'),
          TextSpan(
            text:
                '${oCcy.format(salaryLimit)}',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Any advice?

Comment: Try to put your `Row` inside a `Container` with fixed width

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with a stack? What do you mean by "getting rid of the variable size gap in different sized text"? if you mean that the baselines aren't aligned, look up `CrossAxisAlignment.baseline` shown e.g. [here](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041).

Comment: To just tweak the location of the large text, maybe try using `Transform.translate` , here is a sample https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.translate.html

Comment: @siega Sorry Siega, but that didn't do anything for me. @Edman I think that's what I'm looking for. I added the two properties `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline, textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,` and the characters are all lining up but now I'm having trouble bringing down the the dashed line. [See here](https://ibb.co/wQJ6J2R). If this is a second question that's fine -- just thought I might ask it here. Oh, and took the line implementation from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993380/8213910)

Comment: @Edman I got it working from your advice. I just had to add an intrinsicHeight to the row and wrap the `Container` in an `Align` widget (`Alignment.bottomCenter`). From there the dashed line was a little off from the text baseline so I just added a bottom margin to the `Container` of ten and it looks good now. I can mark your answer if you post one. Here is a [gist of my of my code](https://gist.github.com/Nolence/bf76387534cf83753c0c9c80d2a33a6b)

Answer (score 28):

You can your these 2 lines

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample for you, you can customise the fonts colors and so on.

```
class MoneyRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final String ammout;

  const MoneyRow({Key key, this.name, this.ammout}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(name),
        Expanded(child: DashedLine()),
        _price(context)
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _price(BuildContext context) {
    return RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
            text: "\$",
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .subhead
                .copyWith(color: Colors.grey),
            children: [
          TextSpan(
              text: ammout,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .headline
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.black))
        ]));
  }
}

class DashedLine extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        final boxWidth = constraints.constrainWidth();
        final dashWidth = 10.0;
        final dashCount = (boxWidth / (2 * dashWidth)).floor();
        return Row(
          children: List.generate(dashCount, (_) {
            return Text(".");
          }),
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("My Flutter App"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MoneyRow(
              name: "Cash",
              ammout: "300.3",
            ),
            MoneyRow(
              name: "Cash",
              ammout: "300.3",
            ),
            MoneyRow(
              name: "Cash",
              ammout: "300.3",
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```

**OR**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("My Flutter App"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return MoneyRow(name: "Money $index", ammout: "${index * 10}");
            }));
  }
```

Worth mentioning that the dotted line was inspired by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024767/2315974)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I don't think this is it for me though. If I happen to change the text size of the trailing text `amount` (as I want to do in mine) I end up with the same problem. [See here](https://ibb.co/fkBRfW5)